# Increment Operator in PHP and C Language

Tags: php, c, math, increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

I have encountered with a strange problem regards increment operator.

I get different output of same expression in PHP and C.

`In C language`

```
main()
{
    int i = 5;
    printf("%d", i++*i++); // output 25;
}
```

`In PHP`

```
$i = 5;
echo $i++*$i++; // output 30
```

Can anyone explain this strange behavior? Thanks.

Comment: In C it is Undefined Behavior, So technically you can get any output.Good Read: [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: @Ashwini - Why does it matter? What would you use code like this for?

Comment: In PHP, this is also undefined. See [Example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C the result is undefined because either of the two operands could be evaluated first, thus reading it a second time is erroneous.

And, well, in PHP I wouldn't be surprised if the result was 42 pending some changes to php.ini.

Comment: My religion would want me to upvote because of the mention of 42 but I'd rather not on a closed duplicate ^^"

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of `++` is undefined when used in this style, as you don't know exactly when the `++` operation will occur and when the values will be "returned" from `x++`.

Answer (score 0):

It a matter of precedence. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior since `i++` or `++i` or `--i` or `i--` do not increment/decrement  in any particular order when passed as function parameter.

Not only that but if I'm not mistaken I believe that `printf("%d", i++*i++);` is just outputting `5*5` and then increments `i` twice.

remember `++i` increments before operation, and `i++` increments after operation.
Consider this code:

```
int i, x = 5;

int i = x++;   // i is now equal to 5 and x is equal to 6 because the increment happened after the = operation.
x = 5;         //set x back to 5
i = ++x;       //i is now equal to 6 and x is equal to 6 because the increment happened before the = operation.
```

This is the case for `C` I however cannot vouch for `PHP`.